# Efficient way to call jquery method in jaggerry

Tags: jquery, jaggery-js

I want to use this jquery function inside my jaggery file:

```
$.inArray(value, array)
```

What is the most efficient way of doing it? 
Jquery is already imported in the file using a `<script>` tag. I think using `require()` function to again get jquery  would be inefficient.

Comment: Why don't you just use `array.indexOf(value)`?  It's already built into JS.

Comment: That method is not available in jaggery. It is not hard to write a custom function. But I would like to know how to efficiently use jquery in jaggery

Comment: Seriously?  There's a Javascript environment that is so behind the times that it doesn't have `Array.prototype.indexOf()`?  You could write your own in about five lines of code.  There's a polyfill [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf#Polyfill).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use jQuery in JaggeryJs. Jaggery is designed to run at the server side(Internally uses [Rhino Engine](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/Rhino)). Unless there's a jQuery library for server side scripting you won't be able to do this.

As an alternative you could do something like [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes);

```
[1, 2, 3].includes(2);     // true
[1, 2, 3].includes(4);     // false
[1, 2, 3].includes(3, 3);  // false
```